# Combine multiple VCF files into one large VCF file

Tags: bioinformatics, vcftools, bcftools, hail, vcf-variant-call-format

I have a list of VCF files from specific ethnicity such as American Indian, Chinese, European, etc

Under each ethnicity, I have around 100+ files.

Currently, I computed the  `VARIANT QC`  metrics such as  `call_rate`,  `n_het`  etc  for one file as shown in the hail tutorial (refer image below)

[image is here](https://ibb.co/Cvp2pkd)

However, now I would like to have one file for each ethnicity and then compute `VARIANT_QC` metrics.

I already referred to this [post](https://discuss.hail.is/t/loading-many-datasets-into-single-vds/410)  and this [post](https://discuss.hail.is/t/hail-0-2-merge-two-matrixtable/551) but don't think this addresses my query

How can I do this across all files under a specific ethnicity?

Can help me with this?

Is there any `hail/python/R/other tools` way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Variant Transforms](https://github.com/googlegenomics/gcp-variant-transforms) to achieve this goal. Variant Transforms is a tool for parsing and importing VCF files into [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery). It also can perform the reverse transform: export variants stored in BigQuery tables to VCF file. So basically you need to:  `multiple VCF files -> BigQuery -> Single VCF file`

Variant Transforms can easily handle [multiple input files](https://github.com/googlegenomics/gcp-variant-transforms/blob/master/docs/multiple_files.md). It also can perform more complex logic to [merge same variants](https://github.com/googlegenomics/gcp-variant-transforms/blob/master/docs/variant_merging.md) across multiple files into the same record. After your variants are all loaded into BigQuery you could [export them to VCF file](https://github.com/googlegenomics/gcp-variant-transforms/blob/py3dev/docs/bigquery_to_vcf.md).

Note that Variant Transforms creates a [separate table for each chromosome](https://github.com/googlegenomics/gcp-variant-transforms/blob/master/docs/query_cost.md#i-sharding-per-chromosome) to optimize query costs. You can easily create a VCF file for each chromosome and then merge them together to create a single one.

You can reach out to [Variant Transforms team](https://github.com/googlegenomics/gcp-variant-transforms/issues) if you need help with this task.